# Tennis complementary exercises?

Tags: tennis, swimming

For almost 3 years now, i've been swimming (2km in 35 min) everyday... and for the last 6 months i went back to a old fashion: tennis... i've been playing it almost on a daily basis and getting better at it (currently playing 4-4.5)... I imagine that due to the enormous repetition of the crawl stroke movement it should make your arms less prone to tiredness... Also, its a good cardio workout...

On the other hand I imagine that it does not emphasises the "explosion" part of the movement...

So... Is swimming a good complementary exercise for tennis? any pros swim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, here's a source:
http://en.coaching.itftennis.com/media/113830/113830.pdf

Check the last article about endurance in tennis...